# Centering a stacked bar graph on zero

Tags: charts, stata

I am fairly new to Stata. I would like to create a stacked bar graph that centers around 0 (scale -100 to 100) instead of 1 to 100. Is there a simple way to do this?
Here is the code I currently have and that chart that is produced.

```
graph bar strongly_positive slightly_positive slightly_negative strongly_negative, over(asset_class_name) stack percent bar(1, fcolor(green) fintensity(inten80)) bar(2, fcolor(green) fintensity(inten50)) bar(3, fcolor(red) fintensity(inten50)) bar(4, fcolor(red) fintensity(inten80))
```

[current graph I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JPx0.png)

Comment: See -floatplot- from SSC. A Google for posts on Statalist should get you started.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1681053-stata-centering-a-stacked-bar-graph-around-zero